# Redefine getter and setter for a property in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a provider that redefines setter and getter for a property in `$scope`. The provider will count how many times the property is modified.

I'll simplify the code as much as possible to make it easier to focus on the problem.

**Controller**

```
[...]

export default function(myTracker) {
    $scope.user = 'test';
    mytracker.track($scope, 'user');
}
```

**Provider**

```
[...]
export default function myTrackerProvider() {
    [...]
    this.$get = function() {

        var myTracker = {};

        myTracker.track = function (scope, reference) {

            Object.defineProperty (scope, reference, {

                _ref: scope[reference],

                get: function() {
                    return this._ref;
                }

            });

            console.log(scope[reference]);
        }
}
```

I am sure that I have to use another variable like `_ref` to avoid cyclic calls but I don't understand why it does not work this way.
Why after `_ref: scope[reference]`, `scope[ref]` is undefined?

Update: if i try to run this, the console at the end prints undefined.

Comment: sorry a small edit in get function

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening? I will note that a property descriptor (the third argument to `defineProperty` does not have a `_ref` property, and that `this` inside the getter references the object on which you're defining the property (`scope` in this case). A good reference for this method is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: my aim is to put a counter in the getter, and simply return the value, so i can count how many times a property is returned. I put a console.log at the end to make sure nothing is changed, but it prints undefined (it should print the value of my property, "test" ).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in this way:

```
[...]
export default function myTrackerProvider() {
    [...]

    var counterGets = 0;
    var counteerSets = 0;

    this.$get = function() {

        var myTracker = {};

        myTracker.track = function (scope, reference) {

            scope._ref = scope[reference];

            Object.defineProperty (scope, reference, {

                get: function() {
                    counterGets++:
                    console.log("get calls: ", counterGets);
                    return this._ref;
                },

                set: function(value) {
                    counterSets++;
                    console.log("get calls: ", counterSets);
                    this._ref = value;
                }

            });


        }
}
```

my problem was that **I insisted putting the temporary variable in `Object.defineProperty` function**, while it is **NOT** possible. the only accepted params are the ones listed in the MDN link provided by @Heretic Monkey .
Also, the `console.log` must be put inside the functions (obviously).